Everywhere but a Surface Irrotational Vector Field
The book I'm following takes a bounded open connected set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $H^2(\Omega)=0$ (the de Rham cohomology of 2 forms), and a continuous vector field $v$ that is $C^1$, irrotational and solenoidal on both $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{R}^3- \bar{\Omega}$, and then without much explaination says that $v = \nabla u$ for some potential on $\mathbb{R}^3$, even if $H^1(\Omega) \neq 0$.
Now, my question is, how do I prove that? Is that even true?
